# eclipse new project hg push certificate not verified

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I'm trying to push changes from a newly created project in eclipse to a repository in bitbucket. I guess I have done something in a way I'm not supposed to because I cannot push any changes from the new project.

This is what I've done.

1. I've created a repository in bitbucket.
2. I've installed TortoiseHg on my local machine, all according to the bitbucket turorial.
3. After that, I have commited and pushed changes from my eclipse projects. That far everything was fine.
4. I then created a copy of my eclipse project, without doing anything in hg or bitbucket.
5. Now that I try to push changes from the new project to the same repository as before, I get a warning saying that "certificate with fingerprint ..... not verified. Check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config settings). Further down it says: hg -y push --new-branch https://***@bitbucket.org/myusername/myrepository, error code: -1

Was I supposed to have created a branch? If so, how can I fix that now? I appreciate any help.

EDIT: The reason I had the error was I had changed my bitbucket password...
/Agneta

Comment: What do you mean by "my eclipse projects"?  Is this the repository you created in step 1?  How did you create a copy of your eclipse project (step 4)?  Did you use hg clone?

Comment: Very embarassing indeed! The reason I had the error was that I had changed my bitbucket password (which I had forgotten about). @splattered bits, thanks a lot for your response... I'm not sure I can give you any points, but if I can I will.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're not actually pushing to the repository you think are.  Run this command in both your original and copy:

```
 hg showconfig paths
```

The paths should be the same between them.  If not, you'll need to figure out what went wrong when you copied.  I recommend a fresh clone.

Otherwise, maybe Eclipse is using a different version of Mercurial than you.